# NoWhenBranchMatchedException with exhaustive `when` block in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following sealed class in Kotlin

```
sealed class Result<T, E> {
    class Success<T, E>(val result: T) : Result<T, E>()
    class Failure<T, E>(val failure: E) : Result<T, E>()
}
```

and am returning an entity of Result from a `create()` function

and using the following with RxJava2,

```
    return Single.fromCallable { repository.create(details) }
            .map {
                return@map when(result) {
                        is Result.Success -> CreatedState.Success(result.result)
                        is Result.Failure -> CreatedState.Error(result.failure)
                }
            }
```

The functionality seems to be working as intended as far as I can tell. However when I am unit testing this,

```
    val testSubscriber = underTest.create(newDetails).test()
```

I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` and see a `kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException` in the list of exceptions (when doing an `assertComplete()`), which I cannot understand how it would happen as my when check is exhaustive. Or am I missing something there?

TIA!

Comment: Could it be passing `null`?

Comment: do you mean details is null? (if so the answer is no)

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but might help someone.
I recently had a similar problem, and realized that under tests, I had not set up my mocking framework to provide a valid answer for the endpoint being called. Thus, it was returning null, which is not handled by the when block, which produces this error.

Answer (score 3):

You are using two when expressions. The outer when expression is non-exhaustive.

```
return Single.fromCallable { repository.create(details) }
        .map {
            return@map when { // This is non-exhaustive, you don't need this
                when (result) {
                    is Result.Success -> CreatedState.Success(result.result)
                    is Result.Failure -> CreatedState.Error(result.failure)
                }
            }
        }
```

The outer one does not achieve anything. You should remove the outer when.

```
return Single.fromCallable { repository.create(details) }
            .map {
                  when (result) {
                        is Result.Success -> CreatedState.Success(result.result)
                        is Result.Failure -> CreatedState.Error(result.failure)
                  }

            }
```

Comment: thanks my example was wrong (had a previous optional check before this in the actual code. Corrected the example now (I still get the same error without the outer when)

Comment: Can you share code for :  underTest.create(newDetails).test()